# Appending a file once a word has been found in a txt file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lines

I'm doing a python project for school, and just can't figure out how to complete it. I need to search a txt file, line by line, for a particular word. If the word is there, I then need to append the file 3 lines below the word to add a new entry. Any help would be appreciated! It seems so easy, I just can't figure out how to do it :/

this is what I've done so far:

```
myFile = open("userinterface.txt", "r")

searchlines = myFile.readlines()

myFile.close()

for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):

if (currentusername) in line:
        print(line)  
else:
        print('invalid')
```

what I really  need help with is writing to the file 3 lines below the line I have found.

Comment: Show your effort please?

Comment: (note that some of the rules there may be outdated, see the comments)

Comment: Every accomplishment begins with the decision to try. Post your code trials, search on  internet and don't ask for spoon feeding solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by "append the file 3 lines below the word to add a new entry"?

Comment: My file is comprised of different user's information.

for example:
name /n
age /n
birthday /n

. if the file contains the name im searching for, i then need to add a new entry under the 'birthday' line

Answer (score 0):

lets say I have a file called 'some_text.txt' with the numbers one to ten written out line by line. Then if make a python module called homework.py with the following contents:

```
special_word = 'four'

# assuming this homework.py is in the same directory 'some_text.txt'
with open('some_text.txt', 'r') as infile:
  text = infile.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(text):
  if line.strip() == special_word:
    if i < len(text):
      text[i+3] = line.strip()+text[i+3]

with open('new_file.txt', 'w') as outfile:
  for line in text:
    outfile.write(line)
```

then you can execute it at the command line with:

```
$python homework.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append a text in the middle of the file without overwriting the text following. Instead you can create another file(output file) and write the text in the way you want like this

infile.txt

---

Hello
How are you
Good
Fun
Have a Good Day
Nice
World

```
    infile = open('path/to/infile.txt','r')
    outfile = open('path/to/outfile.txt','w')

    word_to_search = "good"

    lines  = infile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
    if word_to_search in line.lower():
        outfile.write(line+"\n\nNew Entry\n")
    else:
        outfile.write(line)

    infile.close()
    outfile.close()
```

outfile:

---

Hello
How are you
Good

New Entry
Fun
Have a Good Day

New Entry
Nice
World